# Random row with group by?

Tags: mysql, sql, random, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

I try to display a random row of each group with SQL and PHP.
A group is a "category" in my database.

I use this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM images i, set s
WHERE i.ImageSetId = s.SetId
GROUP BY s.SetCategorie
ORDER BY rand()
```

With this code, I've got one row for each category but it always return the first row and I don't understand how to display a random row for each categorie.
Can someone help me, please ?

ps: I've tried other things with date, and GROUP BY rand('e.SetCategorie') but it's don't work at all.

Thanks in advance and excuse my english :p

Comment: Note that in the absence of any aggregating functions, a GROUP BY clause is never appropriate

Comment: For further help, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need *filtering* rather than aggregation.

In MySQL 8.0, you can use window functions:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 
        i.*, 
        s.*,
        row_number() over(partition by s. SetCategorie Order by rand()) rn
    FROM images i
    INNER JOIN set s ON i.ImageSetId = s.SetId
) t
WHERE rn = 1
```

In earlier versions, it is much more complicated. Here is a hacky solution using a *partial* `group by`:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 
        i.*, 
        s.*
    FROM images i
    INNER JOIN set s ON i.ImageSetId = s.SetId
    ORDER BY RAND()
) t
GROUP BY SetCategorie
```

Comment: Hello, I understand that I must not use "group by" this way, thanks for the advice, but I tried to use your code for "earlier versions" but it do not give me one row for each category. (sometime it's the same category, sometime I got 4 rows...).

Anyway, I note that I must search about "SQL filtering" instead of grouping, thank you ! I'll search for solutions.

Comment: @DannyLaRose: I see the problem. The correlated subquery is executed for each row and does not produce a stable resultset. I changed the query to use another technique, let me know if it works better.

Comment: Thanks, GMB but i've tried it earlier and it returns always the same rows (the first of each categorie). It's probably because of the "GROUP BY".

Comment: @DannyLaRose: look closely, this is not the same as your query. There is a subquery with `ORDER BY RAND()`, and then an outer query with `GROUP BY`. Please try this query against your real data.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear earlier ^^ I tried it and it give me always the first row of each category, just like the code I used in my first post.
Maybe it's just impossible to have one random row for each category in SQL :'(

I'll try with the date. If I add a column date for my ImageSet, maybe I can at least have the last images published for each category instead of always the same first row.

Comment: @DannyLaRose: would you be able to set up a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/) with your tables and sample data?

Comment: Oh @GMB i'm so sorry ! I did the fiddle and it works perfectly as I want with your method.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aaf95/2/0
I don't understand why it don't work in my local (WAMP) but I'll try it on live directly, I'm sure it's a probleme with my wamp ^^

Comment: Anyway, thank you very much for your help and patience :p

Comment: @DannyLaRose - you are welcome. And thanks for the making the effort of creating the fiddle.You can see [in the fiddlde](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aaf95/5/0) that you original approach did not work, because `group by` is performed by `order by`: hence the need for a subquery.

Comment: It works perfectly on live, i'm so happy !!! ^^
Yes, it's clear for me, now but I think I should go back to learning SQL before coding anything else :p
Last question, do you have a website or a platform to suggest me for learning SQL efficiently ? I want to be as good as you are, one day ^^